# Why does this happen: Quota 'N2_CPUS' exceeded. Limit: 24.0 in region us-central1

Tags: google-compute-engine

I got the error when trying to create a 64 CPU compute engine.   However, looking at the Quota (IAM & Admin), I see the quota at 72.   Does anyone know why this is happening and what I can do about it?   Thank you very much!

Answer (score 7):

There is a quota set for each of the separate machine types (N1, N2, N2D, etc). You can see your current quotas for this by running:

```
gcloud compute regions describe --project=PROJECT_ID [REGION]
```

See the [Compute Engine quota documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas). You can then submit a request to increase this quota by going to the [Quotas page in the console](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas). Navigate by clicking the Metric pull down and click "None" to clear everything, then type "N2" and select the "N2 CPUS", then click the Location drop down to select the regions you care about. Check the appropriate boxes, then click Edit Quotas and follow the instructions. Typically the quota gets changed within ~2 days.

Answer (score 1):

As this request is quite high and needs capacity planning with our sales team, same with your request for N2_CPUS. We recommend for you to contact sales team [1] for capacity planning, and we will be happy to have someone contact you.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/contact/